# create train and test df inside function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am still quite new to R, and am having some difficulty setting up a function that I can repeatedly call for different seed values (I ultimately want to call this 5 times for 5 random seeds).  All I am doing is splitting one df into 2 df's.  The code within the function works on it own, but when I place it inside of a function to call it with set_data(n), the code runs, but nothing is returned.  The issue that I think is the problem is that the function does not seem to know what to return.  I have tried return(df_train) and return(df_test), but this effort has been unsuccessful.

df_n is the normalized dataframe that I want to break into the df_train and df_test dfs.  I was wondering if df_n is accessible in the function, or I need to somehow pass df_n into the function???

```
set_data <- function(n){
  set.seed(n)
  train_percent = 0.6667
  sample_size <- floor(train_percent * nrow(df_n))
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df_n)), size = sample_size)
  df_train <- df_n[train_ind,]
  df_test <- df_n[-train_ind,]
}

n=1
set_data(1)
```

Any thoughts on how to return the two dataframes so I can use them outside of this function would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: Use a list to return both tables, i.e. `list(df_train=df_train, df_test=df_test)` at the end of your function

Comment: An R function returns the output of the last line, which is in your case `df_test <- df_n[-train_ind,]`. That line of code, however, just saves a variable and does not output anything. With `return` you can return something else than the last line, which is useful in conditional states.  If you write a list in the last line, as mentioned by @docendodiscimus, than that list will be returned. A `return` around that line is not necessary.

Comment: I see...but the problem is that I do not see any of the returned dfs in the global environment...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can put both return values in a list and return that.
I would also include the data.frame to the function call. Then you can input any data.frame.

```
df_n <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100,1,100)
)

set_data <- function(df_n, n){
  set.seed(n)
  train_percent = 0.6667
  sample_size <- floor(train_percent * nrow(df_n))
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df_n)), size = sample_size)
  df_train <- df_n[train_ind,]
  df_test <- df_n[-train_ind,]
  return(list(df_train=df_train, df_test=df_test))
}

n=1
result <- set_data(df_n, n)
result$df_train
result$df_test
```

If you want to assign df_train and df_test to the **global environment** you should change those lines to the code below. This is **not recommended** though and you should avoid it when possible.

```
  df_train <<- df_n[train_ind,]
  df_test <<- df_n[-train_ind,]
```

Comment: OK...I am REALLY NEW TO R...and I think I am doing something wrong.  I copied your code EXACTLY into RStudio and ran it.  I now understand that I need to pass the df_n into the function so it can be used in the function!!!  THANKS!!!  I also see where df_train and df_test are being created.  But it is not returning the dfs into the Global Environment.

Comment: I edited my answer, so you have the result saved in the variable `result`. You most certainly don't want to assign something created inside a function to the global env. If you really want to do that you should use `<<-` instead of `<-`. This assigns it to the global env.

Comment: SeGa, Thank you...I will try the code now...You make a very good point...but my problem is that I really want to use the two df's in another function later...which is why I wanted them to be available in the global environment.  I guess I need more experience to really understand how to properly code...

Comment: @KevinEDow let's say you have a vector, `x`, and you want to know its mean, and you want to use it's mean later. The way the `mean` function works, you would do something like `mean_x <- mean(x)`, and then you have a variable, `mean_x` in your global environment that you can do whatever you want with. Then let's say you have a new variable, `y`, and you also want its mean, so you do `mean_y <- mean(y)` just like before and everything is great...

Comment: ...Now let's pretend that the `mean` function worked differently. Let's say you don't assign its result with `<-`, it just puts something into your global environment named `m`. You might think "how convenient", instead of `mean_x <- mean(x)`, I can just do `mean(x)`. I saved some typing and the `m` result is there! But then you use it on `y` and you do `mean(y)`. Now `m` is the mean of `y`, and your mean of `x` is gone, overwritten....

Comment: Or maybe you had something else called `m`, that's now gone. And later you want to automate this workflow, so you put *this code* inside a function, but that doesn't work. It assigns `m` in the global environment, not the function's environment, which can cause problems. And you have to remember to **never** use the variable name `m` for anything else, because it will get overwritten if `mean()` is ever called in your code, or even internally by functions you are using. *This is terrible*. Confusing, creates all sorts of hard-to-find and hard-to-debug mistakes...

Comment: This is why we don't use global assignment. Have your function `return()` a value (in this case, a `list` of two data frames). Then you assign it where it needs to be, `train_test <- set_data(...)`. You can split them apart if you want, `train_df <- train_test[["train"]]`, but you don't need to. You can just use `train_test[["train"]]` as-is. If you want to use another data set, you call it something different and there is no issue. You can use this inside another function and things will be ok. Others can understand your code because it works the same way as everything else in R.